# Infer estimation accuracy from the percentage of number of trees voting for the majority class?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, caret

I am performing a classification with caret in R. With the predict()-function I can also get a percentage-output of the number of trees voting for majority class. In my case I have 4 possible classes therefore this percentage-value is equal to or larger than 25%.

Clearly, when this percentage value is larger the likelihood of an true estimate is increased:[image]

I am a little bit confused now whether I can assume a simple 1-to-1 relationship between the number of trees voting for the majority class and the estimated accuracy. E.g. when receiving a vote of 70%, can I say that in 70% of cases the estimate should be correct?

I was thinking that a bad random forest that detects the wrong patterns might screw up in this regard. That's why I calculated conditional probabilities. Given that for an estimate of class 1 I receive a vote of 70% what are my chances that the estimate is correct. I performed this calculations based on test data results.
For all classes I could observe a linear relationship between the vote and the probability of a true estimate.
[image]

The relationship is not exactly 1-to-1. Do you think my approach makes sense?

In the end, I would like to give a recommendation to workers in my company based on the vote. If the vote-% is too small, don't blindly trust the estimate. If it is larger than a certain %-value, take it.